# IPublicClientApplication returns the same userid for two separate user accounts

Tags: azure, xamarin, azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-b2c

I have an existing user in my Xamarin Forms app whose Details are as follows:

First Name: Jim Last Name: Smith ProviderLoginId = jsmith@google.com OAuth Provider: Google When I first create this user, I use the following method to authenticate against google as follows:

result = await AuthenticationClient.AcquireTokenInteractive("https://***.onmicrosoft.com/profile.read/profile.read")
.ExecuteAsync();

```
        JObject objToken = new JObject();
        objToken.Add("access_token", result.AccessToken);
        MobileServiceUser user = await App.syncMgr.CurrentClient.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.WindowsAzureActiveDirectory, objToken);
```

Now, I take the UserId property from the MobileServiceUser user variable and store it into my User Table as primary key.

Subsequently, I create another new user with the following details:

First Name: Jim Last Name: Smith ProviderLoginId = jsmith@hotmail.com OAuthProvider: Microsoft

When I create the user using the same steps as above, I get the same UserId back from Azure. Obviously, I am not able to store it in my User table for the second user. This only happens when the first name and the last name are the same regardless of which ProviderLoginId was used (whether it was Google OAuth or Microsoft OAuth).

Should I not be getting a unique UserId in each case? Since the bug surfaces only when the first and last names are same, I am assuming it is some sort of a bug.

BTW, I am using  Microsoft.Identity.Client v4.41.0. The AuthenticationClient is IPublicClientApplication

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: To be clear, when I say it is returning the same UserId, I mean that it is the returning the same sid for both scenarios. Since I use my sid as a primary key for the user table in the backend, it creates all sorts of problems when retrieving user specific data.

Comment: Why is the email not your primary key? *curiosity*

Comment: @FreakyAli it is quite normal to use the userId instead of email to allow users to change the email or use phoneNo instead of mail. For sidsud: login with user1, note the userId. Logout / Clear all data and login with user2. If you get a different userId now, you have a bug in your app. If the userId is still the same, you have an issue in how you set up AAD B2C. With that info you can investigate further and provide more details.

Comment: @AlexAIT, I did exactly that. I cleared out (uninstalled my app, etc.). Same issue. There is not much configuration required in AAD B2C. Not sure where such an option would even exist in the setup. I get the same useId no matter which device I register the user. That is working fine. The issue is when the first name and last name is same for the user, it returns the same userId. When I register joe.smith@hotmail.com and joe.smith@google.com, I get the same userId. I have tried it multiple times with different first and last names. Same bug.